# How to read and parsed Java class as object from file in mapreduce Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have one file which contains custom java objects(POJO) of Address.java with below param.

```
public class Address implements Serializable{

    String street ;
    String landmak ;
    String city ; 
    Stirng state ; 
    String country; 
    int areacode;

    // consider below have constructor and getter-setter methods for all object.

}
```

Now how can i read objects(Address.java) from file in mapper code ?
Actually i am new with hadoop and want read as POJO from file in mapper code.
So, should i have to customize in record reader code or have to implement Writable Interface or anything else?